# How to make this code work with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I'm using jQuery as standard library. However, I had to use Prototype to perform a simple function. But this caused a conflict!

How do I make this code below to work with jQuery and dispense Prototype?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function trim(str){str = str.replace(/^\s*$/, '');return str;}
function signup() { 
    var email   = trim($F("email"));
    var name    = trim($F("name"));
    //EMAIL VALIDATION
    var goodEmail = email.match(/\b(^(\S+@).+((\.com)|(\.net)|(\.edu)|(\.mil)|(\.gov)|(\.org)|(\.info)|(\.sex)|(\.biz)|(\.aero)|(\.coop)|(\.museum)|(\.name)|(\.pro)|(\.arpa)|(\.asia)|(\.cat)|(\.int)|(\.jobs)|(\.tel)|(\.travel)|(\.xxx)|(\..{2,2}))$)\b/gi);
    apos=email.indexOf("@");dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");lastpos=email.length-1;
    var badEmail    = (apos<1 || dotpos-apos<2 || lastpos-dotpos<2);
    if (name=="") {
        $("myResponse").style.display="inline";                 //3 lines to show and style the error message
        $("myResponse").style.color="white";                        // there are more ways to do it using css classes for example.
        $("myResponse").innerHTML="Por favor, digite seu nome";     // you could also make an error function.
        $("name").clear(); $("name").focus();                                       // clear the field and put cursor inside
        return false;
        /*  YOU CAN REPEAT THE ABOVE ELSE IF BLOCK IF YOU HAD OTHER FIELDS IN YOUR FORM, 
            LIKE LAST NAME, ADDRESS ETC. AS AN EXAMPLE SEE HOW THE NAME IS HANDLED AND REPEAT
        */
    }
    else if (email=="" || !goodEmail || badEmail) {
        $("myResponse").style.display="inline";             //3 lines to show and style the error message
        $("myResponse").style.color="white";
        $("myResponse").innerHTML="Por favor, insira um email válido";
        $("email").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        //YOU MAY WANT TO CHANGE THE URL IN THE LINE BELOW
        var url = "includes/optIn.php";
        var params =  $("subform").serialize();
        new Ajax.Request(url, {onComplete:showResponse, onException:showException, onFailure:showException, asynchronous:true, method:'post', evalScripts:false, postBody:params});
        $("submit", "myResponse").invoke('hide');   // Hide the buttom and the message
        $("loading").show();                        // show the loading image.
        return false;
    }
}
function showResponse(req)  {
        $("loading").hide();
        $("myResponse").innerHTML=req.responseText; //Writes the "Thank you" message that comes from optIn.php and styles it.
        $("myResponse").style.display="inline";
        $("myResponse").style.color="white";
        $("submit").show();
        $("name", "email").invoke('clear'); 
}
function showException(req) {
    $("myResponse").innerHTML=req.responseText;
    alert("A comunicação com o servidor falhou. Tente novamente!");
    $("loading", "myResponse").invoke('hide');
    $("submit").show();
    $("name", "email").invoke('clear');    
}
</script>
```

Comment: You think about/look up what each line/command is doing and find the equivalent for jQuery. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Prototype for only one function? You don't need to include a whole library for that. Convert it! What have you tried to dispense Prototype?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try jQuery.noConflict()?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, you will need to change the selectors to use the [`#` id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Also, jQuery does not distinguish between sets and single elements, it always invokes the methods on each element in the collection.

Particularly, you will make use of the `.val()`, `.css()`, `.show()`, `.hide()`, and `.focus()` methods to replace the Prototype and native DOM methods. Also, you will switch to the `jQuery.ajax` function - look them up in the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the replacements you need to complete

```
$F('id') => $('#id').val();

//directly
$("id").style.display='inline' => $('#id')[0].style.display='inline';

//the "jQuery" way
$("id").style.display='inline' => $('#id').css('display','inline')

$("id").style.color="white" => $("#myResponse").css('color',"white")

$("id").innerHTML="Por favor, digite seu nome" => $('#id').html("Por favor, digite seu nome")

//.clear() has no direct equivalent method but this is close
$("id").clear() => $('#id').val(null)

$("subform").serialize() => $("#subform").serialize()

$("submit", "myResponse").invoke('hide') => $("#submit, #myResponse").hide()
```

These are all the simple replacements, I'll leave it to you to do the `Ajax.Request()` convert to `$.ajax()`